# Is it possible to access lists using CouchRest?

Tags: couchdb, couchrest

I am looking for a way to access a [list](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List) I have defined as part of a couchdb design document whilst using CouchRest.

I have tried changing the call from being something like;

```
CouchRest.database("http://mycouchdb.com/db").view("interactions/myview")
```

To

```
CouchRest.database("http://mycouchdb.com/db").view("interactions/_list/mylist/myview")
```

But I get a parse error, and there doesn't appear to be a function like `.view` or any parameters I can set to tell it which list to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `_list`/`_show` functions should produce 'raw' http responses, maybe you want a more generic http library for those?

Comment: @IfLoop you might be right, I would prefer to use the same library if it was possible just to keep things neater, but it might be the best way - thanks! :-)

Comment: er... those features exist largely so you can navigate to them directly in the browser, or to support other client implementations that don't explicitly understand CouchDB (eg, jsonrpc/soap)

Comment: If you put that as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_list`/`_show` functions should produce 'raw' http responses, maybe you want a more generic http library for those?

Those features exist largely so you can navigate to them directly in the browser, or to support other client implementations that don't explicitly understand CouchDB (eg, jsonrpc/soap).

---

Im not a rubyist, so I can't reccomend any particular tool for this, but it looks like couchrest [depends](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest/blob/master/couchrest.gemspec#L30) on [rest-client](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client), so using that wouldn't be an "additional dependency"